# INSERT to MYSQL throwing error due to apostrophe

Tags: python, mysql

```
sql ="""INSERT INTO birthday(team, birthday)
                VALUES ('Norway', {"2020-01-01": "Ram's BDay"}));"""
```

Above sql statement throws an error while inserting.

> ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
> the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server ver

Based on manual attempts I know it is related to apostrophe. Is it possible to insert the above statement, I don't have the control over apostrophe coming in the data stream.

Comment: What is the data type of the column `birthday`?

Comment: Use [parameter substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/902408/5320906) to avoid having to manage this complexity.

Answer (score 0):

you must put the hole JSON String in quotes an escape them in the string

```
sql ="""INSERT INTO birthday(team, birthday)
                VALUES ('Norway', "{\"2020-01-01\": \"Ram's BDay\"}" );"""
```

or you use single quotes then you must escape them in the string

```
sql ="""INSERT INTO birthday(team, birthday)
                VALUES ('Norway', '{"2020-01-01": "Ram\'s BDay"}' );"""
```

**SAMPLE**

```
mysql>   CREATE TABLE birthday(team VARCHAR(100), birthday VARCHAR(100)) ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.14 sec)

mysql>   
mysql>   INSERT INTO birthday(team, birthday)
    ->                 VALUES ('Norway', "{\"2020-01-01\": \"Ram's BDay\"}" );
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM birthday;
+--------+------------------------------+
| team   | birthday                     |
+--------+------------------------------+
| Norway | {"2020-01-01": "Ram's BDay"} |
+--------+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: it works. i have change my answer. there wars one ) to much

Answer (score -1):

You have a syntax mistake

```
sql ='"""INSERT INTO birthday(team, birthday)
            VALUES (\'Norway\', {"2020-01-01": "Ram\'s BDay"}));"""'
```

If you are using more apostrophe be sure to add \ so it will not read

Comment: you must quote the hole string begin with { and ends with }

Comment: outer single quotes are redundant here.